# How can I make the background of a page semi-transparent to show the previous screen in Flutter?

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter, opacity, transparent

I'm trying to develop a screen with a transparent background that shows the previous screen (the one before it on the navigation stack).

Here is what I have so far. I've attempted to adjust its opacity by wrapping the body of the Scaffold in an opacity object, but that didn't affect the opacity of the background. I might be approaching this in the wrong way by using a screen rather than a pop-up bar or menu - I'm new to Flutter and could use some guidance and suggestions! Thank you!

```
return new Scaffold(
  body: new Opacity( // This controls the opacity of the buttons.
    opacity: 1.0,
    child: Column( 
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            _actionButton('email', '/home'), // _actionButton returns a rounded button with the route to push to the navigation stack.
            _actionButton('sms', '/smsRedirect'),
          ]
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            _actionButton('jira', '/jiraRedirect'),
            _actionButton('slack', '/slackRedirect')
          ]
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            _actionButton('override', '/override')
          ]
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            _exitButton() // _exitButton returns a button to return to the home screen.
          ]
        )
      ]
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you push a page, it uses a `PageRouteBuilder` by default, which has an opaque background - see [the source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/eb69f59461077e0115aac6e6f8cb047059da5ef0/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/pages.dart#L77).

It's hard to to tell exactly what you're doing from your code, but if you're trying to make a modal dialog you'd be better of using the [`showDialog`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/showDialog.html) function and [a `Dialog`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Dialog-class.html).

If you absolutely must use a page, it is possible but you'll have to essentially re-write `PageRouteBuilder` to not have an opaque barrier.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom PageRoute. Have a look at this Stack Overflow answer, I think this is what you are searching for:

[Transparent PageRoute in Flutter for displaying a (semi-) transparent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54572107/transparent-pageroute-in-flutter-for-displaying-a-semi-transparent-page)