# Transparent PageRoute in Flutter for displaying a (semi-) transparent page

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Would it be possible to have a page route with a transparent background so I can show a (semi-)transparent page on top of an existing page?

[image: semi-transparent screen transition]

Answer (score 97):

You also don't need to override any class, simply use:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  PageRouteBuilder(
    opaque: false, // set to false
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Page2(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Note: if your new route is a Scaffold with material, the default bg color is white.  You will have to alter that.

Comment: @eimmer Something like `Scaffold(backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5))`.

Comment: How to set it for pushNamed route ?

Comment: @B.shruti For `Navigator.pushNamed(...)`, you will need to return above mentioned `PageRouteBuilder(...)` from your `MaterialApp.onGenerateRoute` property.

Comment: thanks! it's working for me to make the next page with a transparent background!

Answer (score 38):

Yes, definitely! One solution would be to extend `PageRoute` and make the `opaque` getter return false. A possible solution could look like the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class TransparentRoute extends PageRoute<void> {
  TransparentRoute({
    @required this.builder,
    RouteSettings settings,
  })  : assert(builder != null),
        super(settings: settings, fullscreenDialog: false);

  final WidgetBuilder builder;

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  Color get barrierColor => null;

  @override
  String get barrierLabel => null;

  @override
  bool get maintainState => true;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 350);

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    final result = builder(context);
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(animation),
      child: Semantics(
        scopesRoute: true,
        explicitChildNodes: true,
        child: result,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that this would also create a custom transition animation and behave differently than the more complex `MaterialPageRoute` (e.g. the swipe-back gesture would not work with the current implementation on iOS).

You could use it like this:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
    TransparentRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => YourSecondPage())
);
```

For more info on the `PageRoute` and the different implementers, head over to https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageRoute-class.html

Answer (score 7):

You can also use this page route if you want to have material page route transition:

```
class MaterialTransparentRoute<T> extends PageRoute<T>
    with MaterialRouteTransitionMixin<T> {
  MaterialTransparentRoute({
    @required this.builder,
    RouteSettings settings,
    this.maintainState = true,
    bool fullscreenDialog = false,
  })  : assert(builder != null),
        assert(maintainState != null),
        assert(fullscreenDialog != null),
        super(settings: settings, fullscreenDialog: fullscreenDialog);

  final WidgetBuilder builder;

  @override
  Widget buildContent(BuildContext context) => builder(context);

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  final bool maintainState;

  @override
  String get debugLabel => '${super.debugLabel}(${settings.name})';
}
```

and push your second page like this:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialTransparentRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => YourSecondPage())
);
```

Comment: This is clean and great answer. PageRouteBuilder is great but is don't performing real PLATFORM TRANSITIONS. By default there is no trsnsitions. We need to add some transitions. If we want to keep native transitions than is better to override material page route behaviour. When we overide default MaterialPageRoute and add opaque=>false, we mantain native page transitioins.

Answer (score -2):

you need to wrap your widget with opacity like this `Opacity( opacity: 0.25, child: Container(child:Text('hello world')) )`